# Does a chef node need a public IP?

Tags: chef

I'm looking at Chef as a possible solution for a project, and I'm still unfamiliar with its architecture. The first question that comes to my mind is this: do every node need a public IP?

I want to be able to manage a big number of nodes, each in different networks to which I won't have access. I'll bootstrap them in my local network, of course, but after that I'll install them in different physical locations/networks.

Will the Chef server still be able to converge them after they're plugged to a new network with a private address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the Chef nodes can contact the Chef server, everything will be fine.  Make sure your `/etc/chef/client.rb` and DNS is configured to work in the final environment.